# "ng --version" module.js:471 throw err

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to recreate the environment for an existing project combining dotnet core and angular, based on the original versions.
I'm using the free Windows 10 development environment `VM` for `VirtualBox`.
Successfully installed dotnet core sdk 2.0.0, successfully installed node 6.11.4 (with npm 3.10.10).
To install angular cli I used: `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.4`
When trying ng --version, I get the following error, please advise...

```
>ng --version
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\tree\virtual.js:10:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** run `npm update -g @angular/cli`

**2.** edit package.json changing the line `"@angular/cli": "1.6.0"`,
to
`"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0"`

**3.**  run `npm update` will work for this error.

Or else try running

`npm i -D @angular-devkit/core`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried the npm update et al but it didn't work for me. As it turned out using 'npm install -g @angular/cli@1.2.4' worked for me, where as a result 'ng --version' shows Angular CLI 1.6.4 and Angular 4.4.6